# Range Query on a Binary Search Tree (Recursion)

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, range, binary-search-tree

I've been asked to write some code based on a template that will return a vector of keys from a range query (ie. All keys in [x,y]). Bear with me, I am fairly new to recursion also.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
vector<<BSTNode<Key, Value>*> range_query(BSTNode<Key, Value>* root,Key key1,Key key2) {

vector<BSTNode<Key, Value>*> found;
if(key1 > key2) return found;

while(root != NULL){
    range_query(root->left,key1,key2);
    range_query(root->right,key1,key2);
    if(root->key >= key1 && root->key <= key2) found.push_back(root);
}
```

Since I'm assuming that the order does not matter within the vector, would this be the correct way to traverse and store the keys in the vector? Also, how would I return the finished vector at the end of the recursion?

Comment: Is this binary search tree. What do you mean by keys from a range. Does this mean returning all nodes under that key1 and key2?. Also please share how the structure is arranged. Are key random spaced or in some order

Comment: It is a binary search tree. The idea is to traverse the tree and return a vector containing all the keys(or values of the nodes) that are in between the constraints specified. x is an element of [key1,key2] where key1 <= x <= key2. The tree is randomized, with the root at the top and repeating with the left child being less and right child being greater.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in as parameter ( reference to vector ) and update inside your function:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
void range_query(BSTNode<Key, Value>* root, Key key1, Key key2, vector<<BSTNode<Key, Value>*>& found) 
{
    if (!root) return;
    if(key1 > key2) return;

    range_query(root->left,key1,key2,found);
    range_query(root->right,key1,key2,found);

    if(root->key >= key1 && root->key <= key2) 
        found.push_back(root);
    }
}
```

I have modified your code a bit.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that I was re instantiating the vector with every recursion call. I was asked to see if I can do it without modifying the parameters. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: @Lakeside: make it static or global! does that count?

Comment: I don't believe so, placing a variable outside of the function would most likely be unacceptable. I'm not even sure how I would use iteration, recursion seems much more cleaner. I'm looking back in some notes of recursion of how to retain the data.

Comment: You will have to pass the variable (via reference) that you would like to retain or make it static.

Comment: If I declared the vector static within the function would that be the solution I am looking for?